# HTML is being appended at the end of JSON data, how can i separate them?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm submitting values of a form to another file that processes them but that file also has HTML code in it. I'm echoing json_encode() on that file in order to return the response but the HTML gets appended at the end of the JSON data like this:

```
"{"firstname":"levi","secondname":"johnson"}<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>"
```

i want them separate as its messing up the JSON data i want to return. when i remove the HTML part of the file it works fine.
I have tried using a content-type header on the php part but it doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return both JSON and HTML in AJAX call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457328/return-both-json-and-html-in-ajax-call)

Comment: you should not use the same file for rendering html and json in the first place. just do another file for your json-response, maybe in another directory as well. this way you will have a much better overview once your project gets bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 4):

Try ending the response from the server code by putting an `exit;` right after returning the json.

Comment: but what if the HTML comes before the JSON?

Comment: You should not use a single page for serving both HTML and JSON. Keep a separate file which always returns JSON.

Comment: what do i do if the array i want to encode is in another file?

Answer (score 1):

In the AJAX backend file, send some parameter like from where the request came.

If its JSON, then put proper json header.

And `exit` there.

Else, show plain HTML.

This way, your file should also work for plain HTML along with this JSON request.

Just writing `exit` in your code will break your functionality where this file's HTML is required.